# Find the values of $x$ satisfying $\sin^{-1}(|\sin x|)-\cos^{-1}(\cos x)\ge0$ in $[0, 2\pi]$

Tags: trigonometry

Find the values of $x$ satisfying $\sin^{-1}(|\sin x|)-\cos^{-1}(\cos x)\ge0$ in $[0, 2\pi]$. I think it would be better explained by drawing the graphs.

Kindly help me in this question.

Comment: Well it's gonna take lot of works on domain but an easy way would be to understand nature of individual graph and use it to infer this one.
You can use this : https://www.desmos.com/calculator

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

First of all, recount the principal values of $\sin^{-x},\cos^{-1}x$

Now, $|\sin x|=+\sin x$ if $0\le x\le\pi$

and $|\sin x|=-\sin x$ if $\pi<x\le2\pi$

Again for  $0\le x\le\pi,\sin^{-1}|\sin x|=x$ if $0\le x\le\dfrac\pi2$ and $=\pi-x$ if $\dfrac\pi2<x\le\pi$

and for $\pi<x\le2\pi,\sin^{-1}|\sin x|=\sin^{-1}(-\sin x)=\sin^{-1}[\sin(-x)]$

Now
$\sin^{-1}[\sin(-x)]=-x$ if $-\dfrac\pi2\le-x\le\dfrac\pi2\iff-\dfrac\pi2\le x\le\dfrac\pi2$

and $\pi-x$ if $-\dfrac\pi2\le\pi-x\le\dfrac\pi2\iff\dfrac\pi2\ge x-\pi\ge-\dfrac\pi2\iff\dfrac\pi2\le x\le\dfrac{3\pi}2$

Answer (score 0):

For $0\leq x \leq \pi/2$

We can write the above statement simply as

$x-x \geq 0$

Which is true,

For next interval, $\pi/2 \leq x \leq \pi$

We can have,

$\sin x$ is positive in that domain however the $x \notin$ Principal domain. And $\cos x$ is already in it's principal domain. To get it back to principal domain we write it as.

$\sin^{-1}(\sin (\pi - x)- \cos^{-1}(\cos x) $

=$\pi - x -x$
=$\pi - 2x\leq 0$ $\forall$ values of $x\in [\pi/2 ,\pi]$

I am sure you can take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same if you look at $f(x)=\arcsin(|\sin x|)-\arccos(\cos x)$ in the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$, which also allows for a further simplification, because
$$
f(-x)=\arcsin(|\sin(-x)|)-\arccos(\cos x)=f(x)
$$
Thus we just need to look at the interval $[0,\pi]$ and it seems natural to split the study the two halves.

If $x\in[0,\pi/2]$, we have $|\sin x|=\sin x$ and $\arcsin\sin x=x$; similarly, $\arccos\cos x=x$, so $f(x)=0$.

If $x\in[\pi/2,\pi]$, we have $|\sin x|=\sin x$ and $\arcsin\sin x=\pi-x$; also $\arccos\cos x=x$, so $f(x)=\pi-x-x=\pi-2x\le0$.